# What is the value of this limit?

Tags: limits

How do you find the value of limits such as this, in a short way without rationalizing?

$$L=\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(\sqrt[11]{\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{11}\left(2x+\frac{n(2n+1)}{2}\right)}-2x\right)$$

This gets very ugly when you even try to rationalize it.

**EDIT**

Here is what i got after factoring $2x$ out.

$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left[2x\left(\sqrt[11]{1+\dfrac{(\text{something})x^{10}+(\text{something else})x^9+....}{2^{11}x^{11}}}-1\right)\right]$$

Comment: Sorry for the typo's..

Comment: Yeah it does..$11$ terms

Comment: under the root sign you have a polynomial of x of degree 11 with the leading coefficient 2^11

Comment: @NilanC.Manoj How does taking the $2^{11}$ out help? (I agree $2$ is common in both the terms).

Comment: That polynomial > 2X+ x^(10/11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$P(x) = \displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{11} \left( 2x+ \frac{n(2n+1)}{2} \right)$$
We may write $P(x) = (2x+c)^{11} + Q(x)$ where $c$ is a constant chosen such that $Q$ has degree at most $9$. Then, by generalized binomial theorem, $$(P(x))^{1/11} = 2x+c + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)$$ Hence the limit is the constant $c$. It remains to compute $c$. Expanding both $P$ and $(2x+c)^{11}$ and equating the coefficients of $x^{10}$, we see $$\binom{11}{1} 2^{10} c = 2^{10} \sum_{n=1}^{11} \frac{n(2n+1)}{2}$$ Solving gives $c=49$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Wolfram Alpha I got 49. ([No joke](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%20to%20%5Cinfty%20%28%283%2F2%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%285%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%2821%2F2%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%2818%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%2855%2F2%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%2839%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%28105%2F2%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%2868%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%28171%2F2%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%28105%20%2B%202%20x%29%20%28253%2F2%20%2B%202%20x%29%29%5E%281%2F11%29%20-%202x)).

Update: My Ruby ball tells me it converges against 49 as well, which seems to be the arithmetic mean. (I found an index off by one bug)

Here is the upper bound using geometric vs. arithmetic mean:

$$
\begin{align}
p(x) & := \sqrt[11]{\prod_{n=1}^{11} 2x + \frac{n(2n+1)}{2}} - 2x \\
& \le \left(\frac{1}{11} \sum_{n=1}^{11} \left(2x + \frac{n(2n+1)}{2}\right) \right) - 2x \\
& \le \frac{1}{11} \sum_{n=1}^{11} \frac{n(2n+1)}{2} \\
& \le \frac{1}{22} \left(2 \sum_{n=1}^{11} n^2 + \sum_{n=1}^{11} n \right)\\
& \le \frac{1}{22} \left( 2\frac{2\cdot 11^3+3\cdot 11^2+11}{6} + 
\frac{11^2 + 11}{2}\right) \\
& \le 49    
\end{align}
$$
Trying the harmonic mean:

$$
\begin{align}
p(x) & \ge \frac{11}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{11} \frac{1}{2x + \frac{n(2n+1)}{2}}}
- 2x \\
& \ge \frac{11}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{11} \frac{2}{4x + n(2n+1)}}
- 2x \\
\end{align}
$$

But I get stuck there.

Comment: @Pkwssis I resorted to brute machine force finally.

Comment: Is there no analytical way?

Comment: I hope there is, because that query or answer could be wrong.